# Symfony3 & Assetics : Path to node executable could not be resolved

Tags: server, symfony, assetic

I encountered the problem quoted in the title,

```
[RuntimeException]                              
Path to node executable could not be resolved.
```

and it occurs when I dump my assets on an Symfony project (>3.0) only on the distant server (OVH), but it works fine if I am on the local one. I use uglifycss for minifying the stylesheets.

How is it possible then ? Why just on the distant server, knowing that I installed npm_modules locally, on the app folder, so that the situation is identical on both :

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        uglifycss:
            bin: %kernel.root_dir%/npm/node_modules/.bin/uglifycss
```

I hope someone encountered that too and eventually found out why it didn't work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you remote server actually has `uglifycss` in that particular location?

Comment: Yes absolutely, that was one of the first things I checked, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that node is installed;
2. If still node executable is not resolved, then find your node executable path (`whereis node` i.e) and put this path in app/config/config.yml

   ```
    assetic:
        node: /usr/local/bin/node
   ```

Comment: Ok, thank you for the answer. But I don't want to install node modules on /usr directiry, but locally on the app directory, as doc explains it. Why ? Because it is impossible to install node on my remote server at the moment, it is shared, not only for me

Comment: Oh sorry, I see your point now. So I am compelled to install node right ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, you can not run node scripts (which is uglifycss) without node interpreter.

Comment: If you want to use node to manage your assets without installing node on server, you can use gulp or grunt to compile assets locally and then copy them on server.